# Regex for multiline android java

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am trying to make a remarks field for my app which uses a multi-line field. I'm also using an Android library ([Android saripaar](https://github.com/ragunathjawahar/android-saripaar)) which has a pattern feature for regex, I've managed to search for a pattern for the minimum requirements of the field but I'm stuck on the multi-line part because the pattern doesn't accept multiline inputs.

```
@NotEmpty(message = "Please Input a remark")
@Pattern(regex = "^[0-9a-z A-ZäöüÄÖÜ_\\-'.?,]+$[\\s\\S]*" ,  message = "Enter a valid remark ")
TextView remarks;
```

Comment: "That will still"? What does that mean? Do you know about regexp flags (?:?)?

Comment: Is it a limitation of the library? You don't need a library to do regex pattern matching. Perhaps try without.